# Meteorhack:Cluster subscription call failure

Tags: meteor, cluster-computing, ddp

I have an UI app on port 8001 and an app named contract on port 7001. I have 'cluster' installed and working. I have a subscription and insert method defined in 'contract' app.

#### 'contract' server/app.js

```
Cluster.connect("mongodb://<username>:<passwd>@URL");
var options = {
    endpoint: "http://localhost:7001",
    balancer: "http://localhost:7001", // optional
    uiService: "web" // (optional) read to the end for more info
};
Cluster.register("contracts", options);

var Contracts = new Meteor.Collection('contracts');

Meteor.methods({
    addContract: addContract,
    findContracts: findContracts
});

Meteor.publish("getContracts", function () {
    return Contracts.find({});
});

function addContract(c){
    var data = {
        id: c.id,
        type: c.type
    };
    Contracts.insert(data);
}

function findContracts(){
    var contracts = Contracts.find().fetch();
    return contracts;
}
```

I am accessing the methods from an angular controller in my UI app.

UI app server/app.js

```
Cluster.connect(mongodb://<username>:<passwd>@URL");
var options = {
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8001",
    balancer: "http://localhost:8001" // optional
    //uiService: "web" // (optional) read to the end for more info
};
Cluster.register("web", options);
Cluster.allowPublicAccess("contracts");
```

UI app controller code

```
var contractConn = Cluster.discoverConnection('contracts');
            contractConn.subscribe('getContracts');
            var SubscribedContracts = new Mongo.Collection('SubscribedContracts', {connection: contractConn});
            console.log('status', contractConn.status());
            vm.contracts = SubscribedContracts.find({}).count();
            contractConn.call("findContracts", function(err, result) {
                if(err) {
                    throw err ;
                }
                else {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
```

This is what is happening:
* I can access methods on the contract server
* I can insert or find contracts using these methods
* My **subscription is not working**. fetch on the cursor shows 0 and count shows 0
* Status on the connection shows 'connecting'

What am I doing wrong with my subscription?

Sudi

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the name of the client mongo collection to the same name as the name of the collection on the service.